# Ruby: importing two modules/classes of the same name

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When my system requires two classes or modules of the same name, what can I do to specify which I mean?

I'm using rails (new to it), and one of my models is named "Thread".  When I try to refer to the class "Thread" in thread_controller.rb, the system returns some other constant of the same name.

```
<thread.rb>
class Thread < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.some_class_method
  end

end

<thread_controller.rb>
class ThreadController < ApplicationController

  def index
    require '../models/thread.rb'
    @threads = Thread.find :all
  end

end
```

When I try Thread.find(), I get an error saying that Thread has no method named find.  When I access Thread.methods, I don't find my some_class_method method among them.

Any help?  (And don't bother posting "just name your model something else."  It's not helpful to point out obvious compromises.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put your app into its own namespace.

```
<my_app/thread.rb>
module MyApp
  class Thread
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

No really, name your model something else.

`Thread` is a reserved constant in Ruby and overriding that constant is only going to make you run into trouble. I compromised for [my application](http://github.com/radar/rboard) and called it `Topic` instead.

Comment: Okay.  That was better than the usual 'change your name' response.  Thanks.  ...Still, I'd like to know a more general answer, which would be of use in cases not dealing with a duplication of a reserved constant.

Answer (score 2):

If you absolutely must overwrite an existing constant, you can do something like this:

```
# use Object to make sure Thread is overwritten globally
# use `send` because `remove_const` is a private method of Object
# Can use OldThread to access already existing Thread
OldThread = Object.send(:remove_const, :Thread)

# define whatever you want here
class MyNewThread 
  ...
end

# Now Thread is the same as MyNewThread
Object.send(:const_set, :Thread, MyNewThread)
```

Obviously anything that relied on the pre-existing `Thread` would be busted unless you did some kind of monkey-patching.

Just because this kind of thing can be done, doesn't mean it should be. But in certain circumstances it can be handy, for example in tests you can override a remote data source with your own 'dumb' object.